# Global keyword behaviour in python inside a block

Tags: python, global-variables

**Case 1**

```
x = 0
def set_x(n):
    global x
    if n%2==0:
        x=n
    else:
        x = -1

set_x(10)
print(x)
```

Expected Output: `10`
Actual Output: `10`

This output is the very expected, and that is how `global` keyword behaves.

**Case 2**

```
x = 0
def set_x(n):
    if n%2==0:
        global x
        x=n
    else:
        x = -1

set_x(10)
print(x)
```

Expected Output: `0`
Actual Output: `10`

If my understanding of `global` is correct, how the `global` keyword for `global x` in if block affected the local keyword `x` in the else block. I believe those are two different blocks.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: You have already explained the behavior. `if` statements don't have their own namespace.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why do you expect `0` here when `10%2 == 0` is true?  `x` is updated to `n`.

Comment: @theausome It is just for a demo. I have different use case in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > The `global` statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block.

   `if` does not introduce a new *code block*.

   > A *block* is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition.
2. > `global` is a directive to the parser.

   `if` is being evaluated at runtime, but `global` is picked up by the parser. The parser doesn't care about and cannot evaluate `if` statements.

<sub>Excerpts from https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html.</sub>

In other words, any `global` statement anywhere within a function definition always applies throughout the entire function.